Understanding DNS IPv6 result using dnsmasq
I'm new to IPv6.
I've redirected a domain to 0.0.0.0 on dnsmasq DNS server like so:
address=/domain.com/0.0.0.0

when I use nslookup on this domain using my DNS server I get the following result:
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    domain.com
Addresses:  2606:4700::6812:a07e
          2606:4700::6812:907e
          2606:4700::6812:dff8
          2606:4700::6812:eff8
          2606:4700::6812:b07e
          0.0.0.0

My questions are:
Where all those IPv6 addresses came from?
Is my dns resolve configuration to 0.0.0.0 can be ignored and IPv6 address can be picked for the connection?
How can I ping those IPv6 IPs?
How can I prevent those IPv6 resolves to not appear on the DNS result?

There seems to be no entry for IPv6 like address=/domain.com/::

ping6 2606:4700::6812:eff8

@M.Behrens I've used domain.com domain as fake domain for this example the real domain is experience.tinypass.com

$ ping6 2606:4700::6812:eff8 ==>> PING 2606:4700::6812:eff8 (2606:4700::6812:eff8): 56 data bytes ping6: can't create raw socket: Address family not supported by protocol on other machine $ ping6 2606:4700::6812:a07e ==>> ping6: connect: Network is unreachable

Then just add address=/domain.com/::

Thanks, Is it possible to disable ipv6 resolving for all DNS requests? what will be the consequences of that?
